# Django template tag content missing when extending admin app base template

Tags: django, templates, admin

So I am creating a page in my Django project that essentially just uses the Django admin app header and footer.
I have a template folder in the root of my project where I have my base.html.

/templates/admin/base.html

```html
{% load i18n static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-us" }}" {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}dir="rtl"{% endif %}>
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'js-stack/assets/css/spark-styles.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}" />
{% block extrastyle %}{% endblock %}
{% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet_rtl %}{% static "admin/css/rtl.css" %}{% endblock %}" />{% endif %}
{% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
{% block blockbots %}<meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />{% endblock %}
</head>
{% load i18n %}

<body class="{% if is_popup %}popup {% endif %}{% block bodyclass %}{% endblock %}"
  data-admin-utc-offset="{% now "Z" %}">

<!-- Container -->
<div id="container">

    {% if not is_popup %}
    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="header">
        <div id="branding">
        {% block branding %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        {% block usertools %}
        {% if has_permission %}
        <div id="user-tools">
            {% block welcome-msg %}
                {% trans 'Welcome,' %}
                <strong>{% firstof user.get_short_name user.get_username %}</strong>.
            {% endblock %}
            / <a href="/analytics">View Analytics</a> /
            {% block userlinks %}
                {% if site_url %}
                    <a href="{{ site_url }}">{% trans 'View site' %}</a> /
                {% endif %}
                {% if user.is_active and user.is_staff %}
                    {% url 'django-admindocs-docroot' as docsroot %}
                    {% if docsroot %}
                        <a href="{{ docsroot }}">{% trans 'Documentation' %}</a> /
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                {% if user.has_usable_password %}
                <a href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% trans 'Change password' %}</a> /
                {% endif %}
                <a href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}">{% trans 'Log out' %}</a>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <!-- END Header -->
    {% block breadcrumbs %}
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
    {% if title %} &rsaquo; {{ title }}{% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
    {% endif %}

    {% block messages %}
        {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messagelist">{% for message in messages %}
          <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
        {% endfor %}</ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock messages %}

    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="content" class="{% block coltype %}colM{% endblock %}">
        {% block pretitle %}{% endblock %}
        {% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1>{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}{% endblock %}
        {% block content %}
        {% block object-tools %}{% endblock %}
        {{ content }}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
        <br class="clear" />
    </div>
    <!-- END Content -->

    {% block footer %}<div style="padding: 10px 40px;" id="footer"><img src="{% static 'wifispark-logo.png' %}"></div>{% endblock %}
</div>
<!-- END Container -->

</body>
</html>
```

So this is a copy of the admin app base.html, but with a few modificatio0ns such as an image in the footer. This is all working as expected when I log into the admin app.
I also have another app called 'analytics' inside my project. Below is the template for it where I have extended the admin/base.html.

```html
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Now, when I view my analytics page it loads with all the expected header and footer styling from the admin/base.html, but there is content missing such as the admin app title and the menu links, both of which are pulled through from admin app template tags.
Can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong or am missing?

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 4):

In your View, the one that renders the analytics page make sure you pass user, site_header, has_permission, and site_url as parameters.

These parameters can be extracted like this:

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
            pass
mysite = MyAdminSite()
```

And then return them while rendering your template:

```
def get(self, request):
    return render(request, 'analytics.html',  {'user': request.user,'site_header': mysite.site_header,'has_permission': mysite.has_permission(request), 'site_url': mysite.site_url})
```

Hope that helps